# Cannot use XmlMapper (Jackson-dataformat-xml) in Spring boot, error: requiresPropertyOrdering()Z

Tags: java, xml, spring, maven, spring-boot

I've used Spring Boot version 1.5.2 with Maven default pom.xml

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
...
```

Because Spring Boot does not have XmlMapper from Maven: jackson-dataformat-xml, so I added this dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

and check the Jackson dependencies for project, all of them have same version 2.8.7 (newest).

```
    mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.fasterxml.jackson.core
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:tree (default-cli) @ demo ---
[INFO] com.example:demo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.7:compile
[INFO] \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.7:compile
```

And when I run the application, it cannot start as there is an error in Spring Boot for NoSuchMethod found.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter]: Factory method 'httpPutFormContentFilter' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory.requiresPropertyOrdering()Z
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:564) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.<init>(ObjectMapper.java:474) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.java:588) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.<init>(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:57) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.<init>(AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter.java:61) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:63) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.<init>(OrderedHttpPutFormContentFilter.java:29) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
```

Any idea for this problem? I want to use XmlMapper from Jackson library to deserialize/serialize XML string to object and vice-versa (not from the HTTPRequest but internally).

Here is the full pom.xml for Maven https://pastebin.com/LMujJY7e

Comment: You have an incompatible version of parts of Jackson somewhere on your classpath. You can launch the JVM with `-verbose:class` to learn where

Comment: @AndyWilkinson the problem is not simple from the classpath, but from the internal of other dependencies which uses the older version of Jackson. I tried to print all the classpath and they only print the Maven local repository .m2/repository and no older Jackson showed here.

Comment: As I said in my earlier comment, launching the JVM with `-verbose:class` will tell you from where those old classes at being loaded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have run into a problem of version compatibility of dependencies.

I use spring boot 1.5.2 with jackson-dataformat-xml without any problems.

This is part of my build.gradle

```
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
}

compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:2.8.5'
```

hope it helps

Comment: thanks for your post, I think the problem is one of my dependency using the older version of Jackson XML Mapper internally, I still have to find it out as I tried to create a clean Spring Boot application and it could use the XML Jackson dependency version 2.8.7 without problem.

Comment: @BằngRikimaru how did you figure this out? were you able to find the issue in spring boot old version? I cant upgrade my spring boot, therefore I need to find the solution instead of just using new version of spring boot

Comment: @theprogrammer I had another library which uses older jackson-dataformat-xml version.Then, I added jackson-dataformat-xml newer version in pom.xml on top, then maven built this newerversion instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please try updating the jackson bom version in parent pom file as 2.10.4. This resolved the issue for me.

```
<jackson-bom.version>2.10.4</jackson-bom.version>
```